# How to perform multiple requests using RestClient for Unity then execute a function when all requests have completed?

Tags: c#, rest, unity-game-engine, promise, proyecto26.restclient

Using this library https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient I want to get multiple images from an s3 server and then execute a function when they're all downloaded. I have:

```
RestClient.Get(url).Then( response => {
            byte[] imageBytes = response.Data;
            string pathToSaveImage = "/some/example/local/absolute/path/to/image.jpg";
            File.WriteAllBytes(pathToSaveImage, imageBytes)
        } ).Catch( err => {
            Debug.Log(err.Message);
        } );
```

but if I iterate through a list of URLs how do I know when all the requests have completed?

New to C# & Unity. Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use 'RestClient' then use proper request to get Photo. You can use following code:

```
var currentRequest = new RequestHelper { 
  Uri = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos",
  Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "Authorization", "Other token..." }
  },
  Params = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "param1", "Other value..." }
  }
};
RestClient.GetArray<Photo>(currentRequest).Then(response => {
  EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Header", currentRequest.GetHeader("Authorization"), "Ok");
});
```

Also if you are downloading multiple photos, try to get the URL for multiple photos as per the Request.

You can know the status by using the following:

```
currentRequest.UploadProgress; //The progress by uploading data to the server
currentRequest.UploadedBytes; //The number of bytes of body data the system has uploaded
currentRequest.DownloadProgress; //The progress by downloading data from the server
currentRequest.DownloadedBytes; //The number of bytes of body data the system has downloaded
currentRequest.Abort(); //Abort the request manually
```

Comment: Thanks! However I have a list<string> of URLs not an endpoint I can call GetArray on. Is there a solution you can think of that works with the list<string>?

Comment: @hot_barbara Sorry for late response. I was away. You can use Loop for your list and iterate once you have completed `DownloadProgress` from status of Request.